# Alternative to `read-number' that does not truncate floating point zeros

Tags: numbers

The function `read-number` truncates floating point zeros; e.g., `(read-number "PROMPT:  ") RET 100.00` => **100.0**

I am seeking a similar alternative to `read-number` that will not truncate; e.g., `(new-func "PROMPT:  ") RET 100.00` => **100.00**

Comment: Just on the off-chance that these values are money, and that they need to be absolutely precise, *don't* use floats, as they are inherently imprecise; a classic demonstration being `(+ 0.1 0.2)`

Comment: And if that was a surprise, then https://floating-point-gui.de/ is your next port of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter `100.00` at the `read-number` prompt, then you get back a `float`, which might be printed differently to how it was entered.

For instance, `0.0000000000000000000001` prints in scientific notation as `1e-22`

If you want Emacs to show the same thing that was typed, your best bet is to read a string.

If you just want to `format` the float differently, you can do that.  E.g.:

```el
(format "%.2f" (read-number "?"))
```